# Посещаемость пользователя на странице профиля

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Нужно сделать статистику посещаемости страницы своего профиля. Вывод пользователей которые посетили твою страницу, есть скрипт посещаемости сайта то есть index.php (движок gamecms(все равно роли не играет, использует PHP 7.2)) так же использует шаблонизатор smarty
Кто может посоветовать как это сделать. Чтобы в бд заносились люди которые посетили твой профиль, потом уже можно выводить из бд брать значение или как лучше?
так же для удобство используется PDO для бд
Нужна проверка что пользователь на сайте(это уже имеется) и что он находится в твоем профиле (Профиль - страница по тиму [https://домен.ру/profile&id=123](https://xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ag/profile&id=123))

Если потребуется чуть больше инфы, дам, очень прошу помочь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. делаете таблицу visitors с полями visited_id, visitor_id. Обе колонки должны быть как составной первичный ключ
2. делаете сервис, который добавляет туда запись если пользователь залогинен (можно даже не проверять, а сделать `ON insert update`, или тип того(в зависимости от вашей СУБД))
3. в соответствующем action-е подключаете ваш сервис